# How to properly configure Next.js as a frontend and Express app as a backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

Currently I have create-react-app for frontend and express server for backend. In package.json of my create-react-app I use proxy like this `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`.
I need to achive the same thing for Next.js app with the same express server.

I just want to be able to use my express server instead of API routes built in Next.js and proxy it like I do in create-react-app.

Do I need to create custom Next.js server even though i'm not changing any of it's functionality? How to do this properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you have to add custom server in next js

install express js then add file server.js in root directory of next js project

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.use(bodyParser.json())
// add custom path here
// server.post('/request/custom', custom);

  
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('Ready on http://localhost:5000')
  })
})
```

after that change package.json file script section

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what about the Next.js features like fast refresh? I lose all of it just because I have my custom express server?

Comment: have you tried it ?  fast refresh and all other  functionalities are working . app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler(); these lines will add next settings in express server

Comment: It was my bad, I used nodemon instead of node. Thank you!

Comment: If you are here still, I have one more question. Do you think is it good to have my API and Next.js app as a one server (one file)? I mean there is a problem that I cannot call my internal API in the getStaticProps() for example (build breaks). But if I would have seperate server running on different port for my express API there would be no problem with that. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Mimoid is running backend on entirely different space a good idea ? or its good to have a server folder inside nextjs app ?

Comment: This is NOT A recommended approach for production servers

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama could you provide another answer for production servers?